# How to display this JSON format using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I have two JSON formats,

**JSON -**

```
[
    { 
        "name":"Alex", 
        "country":"United States"
    }, 
    { 
        "name":"Jaswanth", 
        "country":"India"
    }
]
```

**AngularJS Code -**

I was able to display the output

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results">             
    {{result.name}} - {{result.country}}
</div>
```

But if I change my JSON, I am not able to see the output..

```
[
    {
        "info": [
            "one",
            "two",
            {
                "id": 944589,
                "contractYear": 2014
            }
        ],
        "country": "India",
        "name": "jaswanth"
    },
    {
        "info": [
            "three",
            "four",
            {
                "id": 944589,
                "contractYear": 2014
            }
        ],
        "country": "US",
        "name": "jass"
    }
]
```

How to I change my AngularJS code ?

Comment: JSON returned was originally an array, but now it's an object.  Why did that change?

Comment: I have changed for the testing..

Comment: If you do `ng-repeat` on the object it will iterate over each property instead so `result.name` would not exist, `result` itself would be the name.

Comment: Got you, i have changed object to Array, then ?

Comment: Is this JSON still bound to a property named 'results'?

Comment: Yeah, my intention is to print the above json ? how can i do that ?

Comment: is it that difficult question ?

Comment: The same AngularJS template code should work fine on both structures (your very first, and your edited second). As such if this is not working then you have something else wrong somewhere which we cannot see (code, data format, an error, something...)

Comment: Can you suggest how to write my angularjs code ? i tried using...
<div ng-repeat="result in results">    
{{result.name}} - {{result.country}} - {{result.info}}    </div>

i am able to print name, country,, but info printing in json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-init="init();">
    <div ng-repeat="result in data">             
        {{result.name}} - {{result.country}}
        <br/>
        <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in result.info">
            <span ng-if="v.id">The id is: {{v.id}}</span>
            <span ng-if="(!v.id)">{{v}}</span>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: info is essentially an array of objects, so treat it as an iterable

Comment: Thank you so much Coldstar, 90% completed. I am getting the output as..


jaswanth - india
0: one
1: two
2: {"id":944589,"contractYear":2014}

jass - US
0: three
1: four
2: {"id":944589,"contractYear":2014}

I want to print  {"id":944589,"contractYear":2014} as normal values not json, can you help me to fix that.

Comment: I mean in the second index of 'info' array, we have to print for {{id}} - {{contractYear}}, i have tried to use ng-if but no luck.